# Why reverse pipeline stages in cycle-level simulator?

Tags: cpu-pipelines

In [pipeline simulator exercise](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~skadron/cs654/assignments/pipe1.pdf), it says that:

> Traversing the stages in backwards order simplifies the instruction flow through the pipeline.

Also, in [gpgpu-sim source code](https://github.com/gpgpu-sim/gpgpu-sim_distribution/blob/master/src/gpgpu-sim/shader.cc), the stages are reversed (line `2442`):

```
void shader_core_ctx::cycle()
{
    m_stats->shader_cycles[m_sid]++;
    writeback();
    execute();
    read_operands();
    issue();
    decode();
    fetch();
}
```

Why? What problem it solves? Can anyone elaborate a bit or give a pointer to books/papers on this particular "trick"?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem that, if you put them in "forward" order, an instruction can stream all the way from fetch to writeback in a single cycle of the emulator. An other solution is explicitly emulating the clocked logic between the stages as it would exist in hardware, but it takes more effort that way. Running the stages in reverse is a simple trick that also ensures that instructions properly "wait" at the boundaries between stages.

Comment: Thx. Googling pipeline stage images, particularly [here](https://techdecoded.intel.io/resources/understanding-the-instruction-pipeline/), I am a kind of understand (that each stage handles *different* instructions).  [This slide](http://59.80.44.44/www.cs.virginia.edu/~skadron/cs654/slides/hack_guide.pdf) (page 61) also says that "backward pipeline traversal eliminates relaxation problems, e.g., provides correct inter-stage latch synchronization". But I don't understand what are relaxation problems, and what are other kinds of relaxation problems?

Answer (score 0):

`execute()` will look something like:

```
void execute(){
    switch(decode_execute_op){
        case EXECUTE_ADD: execute_result = readop_operand1 + readop_operand2; break;
        //...
    }

}
```

Then `read_operands()` can simply write to the globals `readop_operand1` and `readop_operand2` to let `execute()` get access to the result.

However there will need to be a way to propagate duplicate data that needs to skip pipeline stages. For example issue and read_operands can forward the execution operation through to execute which will finally actually use it.